# iPhone SDK: verify XML before processing it?

Tags: objective-c, xml, parsing, iphone-sdk-3.0

Is there a way to verify / validate a remote XML (or download it first and store it locally) before processing it and store the info into CoreData or DB with iPhone SDK 3?

Comment: I'm guessing you can write the NSData* object you get from a Network call to a file ? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

In Cocoa you can just download it

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url 
                                            cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad 
                                        timeoutInterval:30];

NSData *urlData;
NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *error = nil;
urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest 
                                returningResponse:&response 
                                            error:&error];
```

and load it into a NSXMLDocument

```
NSXMLDocument *doc = [[NSXMLDocument alloc] 
                              initWithData:urlData options:0 error:&error];
```

and get the nodes with

```
NSArray* tempArray = [doc nodesForXPath:@"something/anotherthing"       error:&error];
```

Don't know if all of this works on the iPhone.

Comment: I'm afraid NSXMLDocument is just not in iOS sdk